# JAVA: For Loops and JOptionPane

Tags: java, for-loop, joptionpane

I am having issues displaying my output into one message dialog box that is within a for loop. It currently displays every output in separate boxes. The goal is: after asking the user for two integers, it should display ONE message box of the prime numbers and palindromes between those numbers. Such as:

"Between numbers x and y: (prime numbers here)

Palindromes: (palindromic prime here)"

I have tried StringBuilder, but I wasn't really successful. Any ideas and tips would help. Here is a snip

```
for (int i = x; i <= y; i++) {
        int k;
        for (k = 2; k < i; k++) {
            int n = i % k;
            if (n == 0)
                break;
        }
 if (i == k) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Between the numbers " + x + " and " + y + ": ");
        String output = i + "";
       //this is where my issues start
       //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output, "Prime Numbers and Palindromes", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
 }
}
```

Comment: This is _expected_ output. Because, you're trying to display message box inside a for-loop when `if(i == k)` becomes true it starts displaying message box until for-loop or if condition goes false.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if(i == k)` is displaying a message box each time it finds a prime and displays it. What you want to do is have all those primes and then show them in the message box. One way you could do this is by using a StringBuilder inside the for loop and appending to it the values you need from inside the`if(i == k)` and then when your for loop finishes showing that result in a message box with `toString()`. Here's how I did it by making the finding of primes a function and instead of displaying a message box each time in the `if(i == k)` using a StringBuilder and returning it as a string. The final output is what you display.

```
public static String getPalindromicPrimes(int x, int y) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Between the numbers " + x + " and " + y + ": ");

    for (int i = x; i <= y; i++) {
        int k;
        for (k = 2; k < i; k++) {
            int n = i % k;
            if (n == 0)
                break;
        }
        if (i == k) {
            sb.append(" " + i + " ");
        }

    }
    return sb.toString();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String output = getPalindromicPrimes(4, 7);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Palindromes: " + output, "Prime Numbers and Palindromes", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

}
```